# Event driven architecture - Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am willing to clarify my magento related doubts with some of magento experts.

1. Did magento use `event driven architecture`?
2. If magento use event driven architecture, `Where` did they use?
3. Give one `example` of event driven architecture in magento:

Comment: please read this article. http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-event-driven-programming-tips-tricks/

Comment: Is this homework? It sure sounds like homework.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Look for the text `Mage::dispatchEvent` in the code.
3. In the method `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::displayProductStockStatus` there is this line that dispatches an event.

   `Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_status_display', array('status' => $statusInfo));`

In `app/code/core/Mage/CataogInventory/etc/config.xml` there is this piece of code. that marks a hook to that event.

```
       <catalog_block_product_status_display>
            <observers>
                <inventory>
                    <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
                    <method>displayProductStatusInfo</method>
                </inventory>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_status_display>
```

This means that the method `displayProductStatusInfo` from the class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer` is called.

I hope I was fast enough and your homework is not overdue.